# Having more than 60 markers on map makes it very sluggish

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

When add more than 60 markers to my map, the interaction with the map becomes very sluggish. 
I have read this https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers, but doesn't seem to elaborate on what amount of markers are sensible.
It's not adding the markers that are slow, but simply the navigation of the map, when markers are present

I have tested this on the OnePlus 3 phone, and the map is simply unusable because of the lag, the strange thing is if I run it on the OnePlus 1, it can handle up to 200 markers without any problems.

I would imagine that 200 makers is an reasonable amount to render, does anybody have experience with rendering this amount of markers, or is this simply too many?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried a lot of stuff, and in the end I cleared all the background processes on the OnePlus 3 and now both maps preform the same.